# i need to get the factorial of 1000000 in c

Tags: c, factorial, abstract-data-type

```
double factorial(int x) {
if (x >= 1)
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
else
    return 1;
}
```

when I try to get the factorial of 1000000 it results in a segmentation fault.please anyone can help me??

Comment: Given that you could represent the value with a large number library, a recursive function would cause a Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how large that number will be? Hint: [very, very large.](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000000%21)

Comment: First of all, don't use recursion. Secondly, you need to clarify what the requirements are since the number you're asking for is not representable in any reasonable form...

Comment: If you want to support a number this big you need a big integer library.

Comment: Do a loop by calculating the log base 10 of the factorial, to give you an idea of how big it is.

Comment: Even without recursion, this is a number more than 5 million digits long. You'll need a special "big integer" library to get an exact result, or else get an approximation with some higher math.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an answer that doesn't give an *exact* value of that factorial, but gives the *power of 10* of that resulting number.

To do that, let use *y = log<sub>10</sub>(x)* that gives the *y* of *x = 10<sup>y</sup>*.

For instance *log<sub>10</sub>(1000000)* is 6 (6 zeroes, 10<sup>6</sup>). And *log<sub>10</sub>(9500)* is ~ 3.98 since we're close to 10<sup>4</sup>.

Then `log(a * b)` is `log(a) + log(b)`, which is very useful in our case, since `fact(x)` is `x*(x-1)*(x-2)*...*1)`.

Now as @dbush said, you cannot loop recursively 1M times, as the stack that holds the return addresses (and local variables) will be overflowed quickly. So let's do a loop instead

```
double d,pow10 = 0.0;
for(d=1 ; d<=1000000 ; d++) pow10 += log10(d);
printf("Result is 10^ %.02lf\n", pow10);
```

Did it, and the result is ~ *10<sup>5565708.92</sup>*, a number with ~ 5565709 digits ...

---

You could also use Gosper's excellent approximation (discussed on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205128/how-is-gospers-approximation-to-factorial-derived))

[image: Gosper's approximation]

a closed formula with no loop needed that gives an excellent factorial approximation. Again the calculation would hit the limits, so doing the log<sub>10</sub>, having *log(a<sup>b</sup>) = b*log(a)*

```
1000000*log(1000000) - 1000000*log(e) + log(sqrt((2000000+1/3)*PI))
```

gives also ~5565708.92, the factorial being ~ *10<sup>5565708.92</sup>*

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a function recursively call itself 1000000 times.  That will easily overflow the stack, causing a segfault.

You need to switch to an iterative solution:

```
double factorial(int x)
{
    double result = 1;
    while (x >= 1) {
        result *= x;
        x--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note also that you won't have sufficient precision to store all the digits of this value.  You'll need to use a big number library like GMP for that.

Comment: Does `double` make sense at all, or would e.g. `unsigned long long` be better than `double`?

Comment: @pzaenger: 1000000! is much larger than either of those can handle.

Comment: `1,000,000 ! is about 8.26 X 10^5,565,708` https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110818092238AAqtV6Z

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know, it's way too large. However, an integer type would be suggested I guess.

Comment: @pzaenger: 1000000! has around 5,565,709 digits. Which integer type were you thinking of?

Comment: @pzaenger: Um, neither makes sense. Do you realize how large 1000000! is?? It has millions of bits. `unsigned long long` likely has 64. The range of `double`'s exponent only goes up to 1024. Even IEEE quad precision only goes up to 16384. There is no way to represent an approximation of 1000000! without custom soft float types with huge exponent range, and no way to represent the exact value without many many GB of memory.

Comment: @R..: it's only millions of digits, not billions.

Comment: this gives `inf`

Comment: @R..: As rici notes, you are overstating the case by orders of magnitude. The binary representation of 1000000! fits in 2,311,111 bytes. This could in fact be calculated by an adept high-school student building multiple-precision integer arithmetic with `uint64_t` arithmetic on `uint32_t` elements.

Comment: Indeed, but the edit window is closed. Note that if you want to be able to print it in decimal you'll need slightly more to store & compute in a power-of-ten base.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to iteratively compute an arbitrarily large factorial without using libraries to handle huge numbers. 
I wrote a solution in Java (for a ProjectEuler problem), that I've verified against google for up to 1000!, and run for 5000! in well under a minute on a 5 year old desktop (probably that slow because it was displaying output on the console.).
Less than 100 lines of code, include comments and printing the output.
(not sharing the code, because that's part of the ProjectEuler agreement).

Comment: True. It would have been nice to know if that question was being asked because that approach makes sense. I had a homework assignment in high school where the teacher wanted us to write a program that could add arbitrarily large numbers on a 16bit CPU (in basic) You certainly can write a program to calculate factorial by storing the values as say a long string of digits, or other emulations. But performance is terrible, and probably barely usable for even this simple arithmetic expression.